# How to pass an argument to an angular resolver api method

Tags: angular, resolver

I am implementing a Resolver in Angular and cannot figure out how to pass the api call method an argument value.  For example the following resolve method getStores() works fine, it has no argument.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IStores[]> {
         return this.storeService.getStores()   <- this works, simply return all stores.
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => of(err))
            );
     }
```

What I need is storeId passed in. 
1. User clicks on the link of the Store they choose on the UI
2. Code behind grabs the storeId and...  then what? how to pass storeId to this resolver?

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IStores[]> {
         return this.storeService.getStoreDetails(storeId)   <- how to pass "storeId" into here?
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => of(err))
            );
     }
```

Resolver is triggered as such and resolvedData is populated with the data returned from the api in the resolver.

```
let resolvedData: IStores[] = this.route.snapshot.data['resolvedStores'];
```

The Route/resolve is configured as such in the app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "stores", component: StoresComponent, resolve: {resolvedStores: StoreService} }
];
```

Any and all feedback much appreciated.

Comment: What's the reason for using a resolver here? If you load the stores in the store component, you can get the store id from the route params (assuming you're adding the store id to the route params that is)

Comment: Reason for resolver is exactly what it's used for, so that the UI does not display before the all the data is returned from the api call. Is there something I'm missing, is there some other mechanism in angular component to prevent the UI from displaying while my api call is grabbing data?

Comment: To me it's more obvious to let your component take responsibility for everything here. You can use `*ngIf` to only show elements once all data is ready. Your app will appear unresponsive if you defer navigation until after the data for the next route has loaded.

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton - This makes sense, and sounds Much easier.  I'll give it a try, test the behavior. If there is any unacceptable UI behavior, I can perhaps handle it with other methods, the good old wait gif for example